# pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: schema "public" already exists

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I am using pg_dump / pg_restore to backup and restore a PostgreSQL database, but am getting some error messages (and a non-zero exit status) from pg_restore. I tried a super simple base case (outlined below) but still got these errors:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 5; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install a fresh, vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 distro (I'm using Vagrant with [this Vagrant box](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64)).
2. Install PostgreSQL 9.3, configure to allow local connections as PostgreSQL user "postgres" from any Linux user.
3. Create a test database. I'm just doing:

   ```
   vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ psql --username=postgres postgres
   psql (9.3.5)
   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# create database mydb;
   CREATE DATABASE
   postgres=# \q
   vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ psql --username=postgres mydb
   psql (9.3.5)
   Type "help" for help.

   mydb=# create table data(entry bigint);
   CREATE TABLE
   mydb=# insert into data values(1);
   INSERT 0 1
   mydb=# insert into data values(2);
   INSERT 0 1
   mydb=# insert into data values(3);
   INSERT 0 1
   mydb=# \q
   ```
4. Create a backup of the database like so:

   ```
   PGPASSWORD="postgres" pg_dump --dbname=mydb --username=postgres --format=custom > pg_backup.dump
   ```
5. Delete some rows out of the data table in mydb so we will be able to tell if we restored the data successfully.
6. Restore the database with:

   ```
   PGPASSWORD="postgres" pg_restore --clean --create --dbname=postgres --username=postgres pg_backup.dump
   ```

The data is restored, but the pg_restore command in step 6 exits with status `1` and shows the following output:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 5; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;



WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

I cannot just ignore this because I am running this command programmatically and need to use the exit status to determine if the restore failed or not. Initially, I wondered if this problem was because I put my database in public (the default schema). I reasoned that public would be created as a result of the `--create` option by pg_restore before the data was restored (which could conceivably try to create that schema as well since that is where my table is), but when I tried the above steps with my table in a different schema, the results were the same and the error messages were identical.

Am I doing something wrong? Why am I seeing this error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is harmless but to get rid of it, I think you need to break this restore into two commands, as in:

```
dropdb -U postgres mydb && \
 pg_restore --create --dbname=postgres --username=postgres pg_backup.dump
```

The `--clean` option in pg_restore doesn't look like much but actually raises non-trivial problems.

**For versions up to 9.1**

The combination of `--create` and `--clean` in pg_restore options used to be an error in older PG versions (up to 9.1). There is indeed some contradiction between (quoting the 9.1 manpage):

> --clean
>      Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them

and

> --create
>    Create the database before restoring into it.

Because what's the point of cleaning inside a brand-new database?

**Starting from version 9.2**

The combination is now accepted and the doc says this (quoting the 9.3 manpage):

> --clean
>   Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (This might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)
>
> --create
>   Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified,  drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.

Now having both together leads to this kind of sequence during your restore:

```
DROP DATABASE mydb;
...
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE = template0... [other options]
...
CREATE SCHEMA public;
...
CREATE TABLE...
```

There is no `DROP` for each individual object, only a `DROP DATABASE` at the beginning. If not using `--create` this would be the opposite.

Anyway this sequence raises the error of `public` schema  already existing because creating `mydb` from `template0` has imported it already (which is normal, it's the point of a template database).

I'm not sure why this case is not handled automatically by `pg_restore`. Maybe this would cause undesirable side-effects when an admin decides to customize `template0` and/or change the purpose of `public`, even if we're not supposed to do that.

Comment: I'm using 9.6, and specifying `--create` without `clean` does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the reason was that I was using `pg_restore` from postgresql-contrib version 11.2 to restore a dump made by `pg_dump` 9.6 to a PostgreSQL cluster 9.6.

After I downgraded my `pg_restore` back to 9.6, this `schema "public" already exists` error was gone, and the restoring process worked as before.

Comment: I had a similar issue but rather than try downgrading just pg_restore in my postgres docker image, blindly adding [--schema=public](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/282770/165626) worked.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was able to solve this problem by first running `CREATE DATABASE target_db;` then running `pg_restore` with `--schema=public -d target_db`. This assumes you only want the public schema, but I reckon that's quite a common scenario.

Comment: This was the only solution which worked for me when migrating from 9.5 to 14. Accepted solution with --create failed as the dump included some extensions. Creating a blank db, adding in the extensions then running the following with the `--schema=public` option instead did the trick: `pg_restore --dbname=existingdb --username=postgres --schema=public filename.backup`

Comment: This also worked for me, restoring a 10.2 dump into a 15.4 DB. I'm still not sure though, why `--schema=public` is enough and other schemas present in my DB like `information_schema`, `pg_catalog` and `pg_toast` can be omitted...

Answer (score 4):

The restore includes the public schema and so does create database. So remove the schema after creating the database so that the restore can create it without error.

Note: Following assumes `-h -U -p` are default and `PGPASSWORD` or `.pgpass` is set

```
    psql << XENDX
    drop database if exists DB_NAME;
    create database DB_NAME;
    \c DB_NAME;
    drop schema if exists public;
    create schema public;
    XENDX
    
    pg_restore -d DB_NAME FILE_CREATED_WITH_pg_dump
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:

in the `db.sql` file

```
drop database if exists DB_name;
create database DB_name;
drop schema if exists public;
create schema public;
\q
```

then

```
PGPASSWOD=DB_pass psql -U DB_user -h 127.0.0.1 < db.sql
```

And then

```
PGPASSWOD=DB_pass pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 \ 
    -U DB_user -d DB_name --create --no-acl --no-owner DB_dump_FILE
```

My pg_restore version is 11.6

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors when using pgsql-pg_restore from version 12 to restore a dump made by pg_dump 9.6.
Changed it to use pg_restore version 9, problem solved.

Comment: this contributes nothing new to the question, as this was already mentioned in an answer.