# What is the key to pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

We have been working on a large-ish PostgreSQL database migration to a Google Cloud VM instance (Linux 14.04) for several weeks now, and are having issues with the final step: pg_restore.

We are trying to restore from a 17GB .backup file. We have tried several permutations of the `pg_restore` command, including:

- No existing target database, include the `--create` flag.
- Connect to existing target database, include `--clean` and `--create` flags (per [these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90258/pg-restore-archiver-db-could-not-execute-query-error-schema-public-alre) Stackexchange [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900888/why-is-pg-restore-returning-successfully-but-not-actually-restoring-my-database)).
- Specifying `--host=localhost` (per 68 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line)).

Several attempts resulted in the rows of the restore being written to the `nohup.out` file.

A few permutations we've tried:

```
nohup pg_restore --host=localhost --username=postgres --password --role=postgres --dbname=dbname_to_restore path/to/data.backup > nohup.out 2> err.out

pg_restore --username "postgres" --password --role "postgres" --create --clean "/path/to/data.backup"
```

When we `nohup` we are getting a few issues in our `err.out` file, such as

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 187; 1259 17762 TABLE ping arcgis
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "geography" does not exist
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "arcgis" does not exist
```

What are we missing? What are the bare minimum flags etc. to load the data into the PostgreSQL database? Are there some environmental considerations we need to address? Why isn't the data being loaded into the db?

Comment: Your question title is anything but specific.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this and the size of the DB (>17 Gb) I suggest based on the official documentation for [version 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pg-dumpall.html) the following:

1. do a pgdump_all

`pg_dumpall [connection-option...] [option...]`

`pg_dumpall > databackup.out`

2. Restore with psql. I have found out a better execution and stability

`psql -f databackup.out postgres`

3. Take extreme precaution with the file encoding. Specially if you are doing migrations among different OS and specially if you are uploading to a cloud RDBMS provider.

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out.

First thing - we abandoned the `.backup` file method and dumped the DB as a `.sql` file. Then we used the `psql` CL tool to restore the database.

Our final hangup had to do with encoding - exporting from a Windows install of PGsql (possibly without specifying the encoding - we can't remember) put out a `.sql` file with Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text.... (We checked it on our Linux command line with file `x.sql`.)

We converted the encoding with the command:

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 x.sql > x8.sql;
```

then the `psql -U postgres db_name -f x8.sql` command then worked. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/112237