# pgAdmin IV and PostgreSQL 12.0: ERROR: schema "public" already exists

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

I have a database backup from pgAdmin III with PostgreSQL 12.0 (Ubuntu 12.0-2.pgdg16.04+1) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I would like to restore this database on my pgAdmin IV with PostgreSQL 12.0 on Docker containers (i.e. [pgAdmin IV](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) and [PostgreSQL (PostGIS)](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis)). The images are: `kartoza/postgis:12.0` and `dpage/pgadmin4:4.14`.

The problem is when I restore the database, pgAdmin IV output shows the following error message:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "public"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 7; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "SCHEMA public"
[...]
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "public"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 7; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "SCHEMA public"
[...]
pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.places_pilot_area places_pilot_area_fk_street_id"
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1
pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.layer_reference fk_reference_layer_reference1"
[...]
pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.places_pilot_area places_pilot_area_fk_street_id"
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

I would not like to show these error messages, because they seem to be warnings and not errors (PostgreSQL is trying to create a `public schema` where it already exists). These errors are not shown on pgAdmin III when I restore using the same database.

There is [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90258/pg-restore-archiver-db-could-not-execute-query-error-schema-public-alre) similar question. According to [that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90319/181099) answer, the error is harmless, but I would like to remove it from pgAdmin IV output.

I've already tried to restore with: (1) default options; (2) `create` option turned on; (3) `clean` option turned on; and (4) `create` and `clean` options turned on; however no success, all previous options result on an error message.

I'm afraid of ignoring these warnings and in the future true errors appear and I do not see them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The errors with the foreign key constraints seem more serious; where do they come from? Normally you get such errors when restoring with a non-superuser. Do you also get them with a superuser?

Comment: Yes, I do. I use a Docker container with a pgAdmin IV image and inside it a superuser is used.

I believe FK errors were just warnings like schema public ones, because when I used just pgAdmin IV to back my database up and to restore it again, it worked fine, no errors appeared.

I tried to explain on an answer.

Thank you Laurenz for your feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pg\_restore: \[archiver (db)\] could not execute query: ERROR: schema "public" already exists](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90258/pg-restore-archiver-db-could-not-execute-query-error-schema-public-alre)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve my problem by another path.

I suspected the problem was related to pgAdmin III and not PostgreSQL, then I opened my remote server through pgAdmin IV and I backed my remote database up.

After that, on pgAdmin IV, I restored the database and it worked fine, with no error.

Then, I believe the problem is related to creating a backup on pgAdmin III and restore it on pgAdmin IV.

If someone gets the same error in the future, please, use just pgAdmin IV to avoid problems.

Comment: Then it is probably different versions of `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` at work.